# JAVA, how to declare array value?

Tags: java, arrays, json, declare

JSON FORMAT

{
"results": [
    [
      "2017-01-14",
      "142413",
      142413,
      "IN",
      3,
      3,
      24,
      2,
      0.0004368
    ],
    [
      "2017-01-14",
      "130019751",
      142413,
      "AL",
      4299,
      4372,
      14044195,
      26,
      0.5490055789436032
    ]
]
}

How to declare java model class?

private Object[] results????

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Have you got a class that those results map to?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is Gson

Using something like`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'helloWorld'}";
YourClass yourClass= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, YourClass.class);
```